# PHP: DOM element shows attributes but hasAttribute returns nothing

Tags: php, dom, attributes

I am trying to get attribute *tagName* of a DOMElement object, called $parent, but when I use

`$attributes = $parent -> attributes`

and then I

`print_r($attributes);`

I get as a result:

`DOMNamedNodeMap Object ( [length] => 0 )` .

But, if I do

`print_r($parent)`

I get:

```
DOMElement Object
(
    [tagName] => Book
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => Book
    [nodeValue] => 
    [nodeType] => 1
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
    [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
    [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
    [previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [attributes] => (object value omitted)
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => Book
    [baseURI] => /home/luca/Documents/Daytripper/userData/0_bookshelf.xml
    [textContent] => 
 )
```

Which to me means that the element $parent has attributes. I think that I am doing wrong getting the attributes.

The piece of code is:

```
$parent = $collection -> item(0);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($parent);
echo "</pre>";
$attributes = $parent -> attributes;
print_r($attributes);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: _“Which to me means that the element $parent has attributes.”_ - no, it doesn’t. Not in an “XML way” at least. These are properties of the `DOMElement` object instance you have here, but that is not the same thing as actual XML attributes.

Comment: If you were referring to `[attributes] => (object value omitted)` – that just means that the object has a property named `atteributes` - it does not mean that this `DOMNamedNodeMap` in turn needs to _contain_ anything, it might simply be an empty map.

Comment: Thanks @04FS . Actually I sorted it out in a different way, getting tagName using $parent -> tagName . 
My understanding is that tagName is not an attribute but a property.